# Flagger canary deployment in kubernetes with istio service mesh

Tags: istio

I have a backend microservice for which there is no URL and traffic is going to Backend Microservice from another Microservice ...How should we ensure or implement is istio  that traffic is flowing to the canary version of the backend ms

Any doc which describe how canary should be taken care for backend microservices